# How does XEP-0114 work?

Tags: components, xmpp

I am a bit confused about how [XEP-0114](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0114.html) works. Does servicing a domain using a component mean that the server will no longer do anything on behalf of that domain, or does it just mean that the component will ALSO be allowed to service all users on that domain.

More specifically, is it possible to have multiple components servicing the same domain? For example, one component could handle MUC, another could store all messages in a history store, and a third could handle the roster, etc... All while the XMPP server continues handling the user like it normally would - and replying to presence, iq packets, etc... What this means is that components would have to be written so that their realm doesn't intersect with each other.

Comment: Server will route all packets to anyone@component.domain to your external component script. I explained in detail about how a component works and how to write one using php. http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2010/08/how-to-write-external-jabber-components-in-php-using-jaxl-library/

Comment: @Abhinav So I gather that all stanzas are passed on to the component, but what about presence subscriptions? Will the jabber server maintain a roster for any user, or is it entirely the responsibility of the component to maintain every user's roster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering @dhruvbird's second question in the comments above, if you have delegated a domain to your XEP-114 component, that component is responsible for *everything* about that domain, including all of the presence states of the users in that domain.  That is possible, if tedious, but make sure you've read the new [RFC 6121](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6121) recently.

Note: most servers have a component that implements all of this presence subscription logic - it's where the real IM business logic is implemented.  You'll effectively be writing a replacement for that logic, so make sure there's no other way to solve your problem first.

Comment: It is exactly what I was asking really. As far as the real problem goes, I was thinking of some sort of setup where you can have multiple components serving all users of a domain, but they all perform mutually exclusive activities. So, one of them does conf. rooms while another does offline storage retrieval and a third does presence. They can communicate with each other externally (say using message passing). But the fact of the matter is that I should be able to add functionality by just introducing one more component. Is it currently possible to do something like this (a XEP maybe)?

Comment: What you want is very specific to implementations - some of them have the ability to plug in new modules into their existing business logic, but none that I know of allow you to do some processing in one component, and some in another for the same domain name.